# Adding a ga send command between a lazy load code

Tags: google-analytics

I've been working on a project with a group of friends using lazyload in order to load the views, but now i want to use GA in order to check how many times an user checks and i would like to know if is possible to add a ga ('send') line between the lazyload, this is one of the lines i'm using for the lazy load:

```
  $stateProvider
                .state('consulta', {
                    url: "/consulta",
                    controller: "consulta",
                    params: {
                        obj: null
                    },
                    views: {
                        "": {
                            templateUrl: "/CM/view/V-consulta.html"
                        }
                    },
                    resolve: {
                        loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load('consulta'); 
                            }]
                    }
                })
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the `ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded` event from the [docs page](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/oclazyloadprovider) can help?